# Error: Transaction reverted: function call failed to execute

Tags: solidity, nft, hardhat

I am currently working on an nft marketplace and wanna integrate a 2.5% fee on every sale. I have read and reasearched online on how to calcuate percentage in solidity and was successful on that part but the problem is that result its a huge number i.e 2.5 * 150/100 is supposed to return 3.75
but i get this figure instead: 3750000000000000000000000000000000000

My test

```
const auctionPrice = ethers.utils.parseUnits("1", "ether");

const [_, userAddress] = await ethers.getSigners();
    let fee = (2.5 * auctionPrice) / 100;
    const commission = ethers.utils.parseUnits(fee.toString(), "ether");
    let commissionValue = commission.toString();

    console.log(commission.toString());
    console.log(fee);

    await market
      .connect(userAddress)
      .createMarketSale(nftContractAddress, 1, commissionValue, {
        value: auctionPrice,
      });
```

The Result

```
250000000000000000000000000000000

 1 failing

  1) NFTMarket
       Should create and execute market sales:
     Error: Transaction reverted: function call failed to execute
      at NFTMarket.createMarketSale (contracts/NFTMarket.sol:165)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
      at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:65:3)
      at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:526:9)
      at processTimers (node:internal/timers:500:7)
      at HardhatNode._mineBlockWithPendingTxs (node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\hardhat-network\provider\node.ts:1602:23)
      at HardhatNode.mineBlock (node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\hardhat-network\provider\node.ts:435:16)
      at EthModule._sendTransactionAndReturnHash (node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\hardhat-network\provider\modules\eth.ts:1494:18)
```

So my question is there any way to turn this number (3750000000000000000000000000000000000) into a decimal or whole number? I have searched but couldnt find any thing online talking about this

Answer (score 5):

In fact there is no problem with your calculation. The problem is the use of the function `ethers.utils.parseUnits()`.

###### Let's do a quick recap first:

Under the hood, all transactions in Ethereum are paid in `wei`, that is the smallest denomination of ether. So, if you send 1 ETH to some contract, you are actually sending 1,000,000,000,000,000,000 wei, because 1 ETH = 10^18 wei.

###### Your code

In the tests, when you use the function `ethers.utils.parseUnits("1", "ether")`, you are atually saing "I want to send 1 ETH, so please convert this 1 ETH to wei to make my life easier". Then this function simply adds 18 zeros to your "1" string.

Finally, when you perform your calculation `(2.5 * auctionPrice) / 100`, the result are already in the right format. So you don't have to call `perseUnits` again, because you are adding more 18 zeros! =D

Comment: But why does it through an error when I want to transfer that amount to the contract owner  ```        payable(owner).transfer(listingPrice);
```

Comment: A bit late on the conversation, but, Were you able to solve it? If so, can you share your solution?, otherwise, Can you post the contract (or at least the portion of it) that it's throwing that error.

Answer (score 0):

I've catch that error when my smart contract tried to call another one, and attached some eth amount, while the total balance of the original contract was less than that value

```
IMyContract(contract).someMethod{value: amount}(arguments);
```

so hardhat test failed with error
`Error: Transaction reverted: function call failed to execute`

hope this'd help anyone like me seeking answers for that error